# Retrieve the HandBrakeCLI command from HandBrake GUI

Tags: macos, video-encoding, handbrake

I understand that the HandBrake application uses the HandBrakeCLI command-line application to do the actual encoding job

From all the encoding settings I've set on the HandBrake UI, how can I retrieve the exact arguments used by HandBrakeCLI ? (on MacOS)

(for example, I've checked "Web Optimized" checkbox : how is that translated in CLI arguments ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [**Activity Window and Log**](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/ActivityLog):

[image: 1]

Comment: This shows the job configuration and dumps all the settings, but it doesn't show you what the command line options for HandBrakeCLI would be. I could spend a lot of time and look them all up individually and build my own command line, but this would take a lot of time. Is there any way to have them prepared automatically?

Comment: Late comment - as of handbrake 0.10.1 the log file does show you everything that is passed to handbrakecli.    One thing that the cli doesn't seem to do is parse the original file for chapter markers - those are passed to the cli in a .csv file, presumably generated by the gui or some other helper.  Otherwise everything seems to be there.

Comment: I'm confused, Dan - I don't see a HandbrakeCLI command line in the log, either. There is a lot of detailed information in the log. It's just not presented in HandbrakeCLI format per se. This is 10.1 on MacOS.

Comment: guys, there is no HandBrakeCLI on OSX. HandBrakeCLI is offical supported and provided on Linux and Windows. On Windows you can see the correct command line in the log window. There are some informations out on the net how to get HandBrakeCLI on OSX.